# Difference between event.value and event.target.value

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

In JavaScript event handlers, what is the difference between `event` and `event.target`? When to use them?

Here are two examples: (fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nszp342t/)

**HTML:**

```
<select id="test1">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<select id="test2" onchange="handleSelect(this)">
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById("test1").onchange = (e) => {
  console.log(e.value); // undefined
  console.log(e.target.value); // works
}

let handleSelect = (e) => {
  console.log(e.value); // works
  console.log(e.target.value); // Error: e.target is undefined
}
```

I also tried `addEventListener()`, which gives the same results as the first test. I could not find any documentation except [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), which does not clarify it for me.

Is there a recommended way to handle events? Is one of my examples considered "bad practice"? If both are correct, is there a rule of thumb / way to remember which one to use?

Comment: I'd start using jQuery rather than just Vanilla JS. Just saying. Looking into more of your question

Comment: event handlers are passed an `Event` object when called, you set the handler to be passed `this` which in that place represents the element causing the event.

Comment: @PatrickEvans thank you! So, is it impossible to pass the Event in the second case? I tried `onchange="handleSelect()"` and now `e` is undefined. Also you could post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are passed differently when using the inline HTML on{Event} attribute. See [MDN Docs here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

> When the event handler is specified as an HTML attribute, the specified code is wrapped into a function with the following parameters:
>
> - event — for all event handlers except onerror.

You can think of this as your code being executed within a function that already has access to the event object.

```
function (event) {
    handleSelect(this) // this is your script that's executing where 'this' is the DOM elem
}
```

You can change the handleSelect logic to use the `event` object instead of the passed in parameter (which in this case is the DOM element).

```
let handleSelect = (e) => { // e === this
    console.log(event.target.value) // event !== this 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

event provides a set of properties that can be accessed. The object properties are accessed by using a dot notation for instance event.target

```
var dog = {
   legs: 4,
   name: 'doggie'
}
console.log(dog.name) // -> doggie
```

event.target.value is called chaining because it combines two properties. It basically retrieves value of whatever input it was called on

See more [DOM API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

Comment: The question was not about JavaScript syntax, but about the context the handlers are executed in.